# C# CIL stloc.1 issue

Tags: c#, cil

**The former question is solved, please proceed to the end.**

So I have this code here:

```
using Harmony;
using RimWorld;
using Verse;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace RandomPlus
{
    [HarmonyPatch (typeof(Page_ConfigureStartingPawns), "RandomizeCurPawn")]
    class Patch_RandomizeMethod
    {
        static void Prefix ()
        {
            RandomSettings.ResetRerollCounter ();
        }

        static IEnumerable<CodeInstruction> Transpiler (IEnumerable<CodeInstruction> instructions)
        {
            var curPawnFieldInfo = typeof(Page_ConfigureStartingPawns)
                .GetField ("curPawn", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var randomizeInPlaceMethodInfo = typeof(StartingPawnUtility)
                .GetMethod ("RandomizeInPlace", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
            var checkPawnIsSatisfiedMethodInfo = typeof(RandomSettings)
                .GetMethod ("CheckPawnIsSatisfied", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

            var codes = new List<CodeInstruction> (instructions);

            var appropriatePlace = 6;

            /* Removing the following code in its IL form */

            // this.curPawn = StartingPawnUtility.RandomizeInPlace(this.curPawn);

            codes.RemoveRange (appropriatePlace, 5);

            /* Adding the following code in its IL form: */

//           do {
//            this.curPawn = StartingPawnUtility.RandomizeInPlace (this.curPawn);
//           } while (!RandomSettings.CheckPawnIsSatisfiedMethodInfo);

//
//          // loop start (head: IL_0016)
//          IL_0016: nop
//          IL_0017: ldarg.0
//          IL_0018: ldarg.0
//          IL_0019: ldarg.0
//          IL_001a: ldfld int32 C::curPawn
//          IL_001f: call instance int32 C::RandomizeInPlace(int32)
//          IL_0024: stfld int32 C::curPawn
//          IL_0029: nop
//          IL_002a: ldarg.0
//          IL_002b: call instance bool C::CheckPawnIsSatisfied()
//          IL_0030: ldc.i4.0
//          IL_0031: ceq
//          IL_0033: stloc.1
//          // sequence point: hidden
//          IL_0034: ldloc.1
//          IL_0035: brtrue.s IL_0016
//          // end loop

            List <CodeInstruction> newCodes = new List<CodeInstruction> {
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Nop),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldfld, curPawnFieldInfo),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Call, randomizeInPlaceMethodInfo),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Stfld, curPawnFieldInfo),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Nop),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Call, checkPawnIsSatisfiedMethodInfo),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ceq),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Stloc_1),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldloc_1),
            };

            newCodes [0].labels.Add (new Label ());

            var nopLabel = newCodes [0].labels [0];

            newCodes.Add (new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Brtrue_S, nopLabel));

            codes.InsertRange (appropriatePlace, newCodes);

            for (var i = 0; i < codes.Count; i++) {
                Log.Message (codes [i].ToString ());
            }

            return codes;
        }
    }
}
```

What it basically does is it alters a method's code in IL and it is supposed to change this

```
private void RandomizeCurPawn()
{
    if (!TutorSystem.AllowAction("RandomizePawn"))
    {
        return;
    }
    this.curPawn = StartingPawnUtility.RandomizeInPlace(this.curPawn);
    TutorSystem.Notify_Event("RandomizePawn");
}
```

into:

```
private void RandomizeCurPawn()
{
    if (!TutorSystem.AllowAction("RandomizePawn"))
    {
        return;
    }
    do
        {
            this.curPawn = StartingPawnUtility.RandomizeInPlace(this.curPawn);
        }
        while (!RandomSettings.CheckPawnIsSatisfiedMethodInfo);
    TutorSystem.Notify_Event("RandomizePawn");
}
```

And in order to get the IL code for the part with "while", I came up with [this example program](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) so I could get the code and change it for my needs but though I copied the IL code correctly (as far as I can tell), it doesn't work and throws an exception that says:

```
Could not execute post-long-event action. Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for RandomPlus.HarmonyPatches ---> System.FormatException: Method RimWorld.Page_ConfigureStartingPawns.RandomizeCurPawn() cannot be patched. Reason: Invalid IL code in (wrapper dynamic-method) RimWorld.Page_ConfigureStartingPawns:RandomizeCurPawn_Patch1 (object): IL_003c: stloc.1   


  at Harmony.PatchFunctions.UpdateWrapper (System.Reflection.MethodBase original, Harmony.PatchInfo patchInfo, System.String instanceID) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Harmony.PatchProcessor.Patch () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Harmony.HarmonyInstance.<PatchAll>b__7_0 (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Harmony.CollectionExtensions.Do[Type] (IEnumerable`1 sequence, System.Action`1 action) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Harmony.HarmonyInstance.PatchAll (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at RandomPlus.HarmonyPatches..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers:RunClassConstructor (intptr)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor (RuntimeTypeHandle type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Verse.StaticConstructorOnStartupUtility.CallAll () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Verse.PlayDataLoader.<DoPlayLoad>m__2 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Verse.LongEventHandler.ExecuteToExecuteWhenFinished () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Verse.Log:Error(String)
Verse.LongEventHandler:ExecuteToExecuteWhenFinished()
Verse.LongEventHandler:UpdateCurrentAsynchronousEvent()
Verse.LongEventHandler:LongEventsUpdate(Boolean&)
Verse.Root:Update()
Verse.Root_Entry:Update()
```

As you can see, it is complaining about "stloc.1" line and I'm not sure why. If anyone knows how to fix this issue, please let me know, I would really appreciate that!

**UPD.**

I'd like to ask another question here rather than to create a separate one.

Here is what's changed:

```
//          // loop start (head: IL_000e)
//          IL_000e: ldarg.0
//          IL_000f: ldarg.0
//          IL_0010: ldarg.0
//          IL_0011: ldfld int32 C::curPawn
//          IL_0016: call instance int32 C::RandomizeInPlace(int32)
//          IL_001b: stfld int32 C::curPawn
//          IL_0020: ldarg.0
//          IL_0021: call instance bool C::CheckPawnIsSatisfied()
//          IL_0026: brfalse.s IL_000e
//          // end loop

            List <CodeInstruction> newCodes = new List<CodeInstruction> {
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldfld, curPawnFieldInfo),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Call, randomizeInPlaceMethodInfo),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Stfld, curPawnFieldInfo),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
                new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Call, checkPawnIsSatisfiedMethodInfo),
            };
```

The game now shows me this error:

```
Could not execute post-long-event action. Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for RandomPlus.HarmonyPatches ---> System.FormatException: Method RimWorld.Page_ConfigureStartingPawns.RandomizeCurPawn() cannot be patched. Reason: Invalid IL code in (wrapper dynamic-method) RimWorld.Page_ConfigureStartingPawns:RandomizeCurPawn_Patch1 (object): IL_003c: call      0x00000011


  at Harmony.PatchFunctions.UpdateWrapper (System.Reflection.MethodBase original, Harmony.PatchInfo patchInfo, System.String instanceID) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Harmony.PatchProcessor.Patch () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Harmony.HarmonyInstance.<PatchAll>b__7_0 (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Harmony.CollectionExtensions.Do[Type] (IEnumerable`1 sequence, System.Action`1 action) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Harmony.HarmonyInstance.PatchAll (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at RandomPlus.HarmonyPatches..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers:RunClassConstructor (intptr)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor (RuntimeTypeHandle type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Verse.StaticConstructorOnStartupUtility.CallAll () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Verse.PlayDataLoader.<DoPlayLoad>m__2 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Verse.LongEventHandler.ExecuteToExecuteWhenFinished () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Verse.Log:Error(String)
Verse.LongEventHandler:ExecuteToExecuteWhenFinished()
```

Do you think it's because I don't pass an argument for RandomizeInPlace?

**UPD2:**

I've updated the [playground](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) and here is my current code and error:

```
    List <CodeInstruction> newCodes = new List<CodeInstruction> {
        new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
        new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
        new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldfld, curPawnFieldInfo),
        new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Call, randomizeInPlaceMethodInfo),
        new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Stfld, curPawnFieldInfo),
        new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Call, checkPawnIsSatisfiedMethodInfo),
    };

Could not execute post-long-event action. Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for RandomPlus.HarmonyPatches ---> System.FormatException: Method RimWorld.Page_ConfigureStartingPawns.RandomizeCurPawn() cannot be patched. Reason: Invalid IL code in (wrapper dynamic-method) RimWorld.Page_ConfigureStartingPawns:RandomizeCurPawn_Patch1 (object): IL_003a: call      0x00000011
```

Comment: How have you ended up in a situation where you can't change the code of the class directly? Wait, are you hacking RimWorld?

Comment: I don't know, I just did :p

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site. As per custom, I point you to the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Please don’t alter your question that way. If you have another question then please ask a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell:

- In your code, you do not have local variables. So `stloc.1` won't work.
- In your example, you are looking at debug code. Which is creating and setting local variables to ease debugging※. Use release code instead.

※: See that the code uses `stloc.0` (set the first local variable) followed by `ldloc.0` (load the first local variable), and they are not used anywhere else. The same is true for `stloc.1` and `ldloc.1`. There are "sequence point: hidden" in between of `stloc` and `ldloc` which indicates position where you could add a breakpoint and inspect the value of the helper local variable.

If you insist in adding local variables, have a look at [ILGenerator.DeclareLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.declarelocal?view=netframework-4.8).

---

**Addendum**

In the original code, you have:

```
this.curPawn = StartingPawnUtility.RandomizeInPlace(this.curPawn);
```

This is doing three things:

1. Read `curPawn` (we need `this` here)
2. Call `StartingPawnUtility.RandomizeInPlace` (we do NOT need `this` here, this is a static call)
3. Set `curPawn` (we need `this` here)

For a great total of 2 uses of `this`. Thus, the code needs to load `this` (a.k.a `ldarg.0`) twice.

Now, the replacement code has:

```
this.curPawn = this.RandomizeInPlace (this.curPawn);
```

Here, the call to `RandomizeInPlace` is not a static call. Hence, the code needs need to load `this` once more, for a total of three times (you even have the three uses of `this` written explicitly in the code).

This is why you have three consecutive `ldarg.0` in your code:

```
List <CodeInstruction> newCodes = new List<CodeInstruction> {
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0), // <--
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0), // <--
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0), // <--
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldfld, curPawnFieldInfo),
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Call, randomizeInPlaceMethodInfo),
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Stfld, curPawnFieldInfo),
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Call, checkPawnIsSatisfiedMethodInfo),
};
```

I suppose you want to do a static call, just like the original code, which imply to remove one `ldarg.0`, leaving only two.

Note: I think you a similar problem with the other call instruction.

---

You can check [OpCodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes?view=netframework-4.8) for documentation on the IL instructions.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try switching it to "release" and see if it works!

Comment: Yes, it no longer complains about "stloc.1" but I've got another error which I'll try to solve on my own first. :)

Comment: I updated my question so it now includes another problem.

Comment: My bad, there is no "this" in the updated code; it's just "StartingPawnUtility.RandomizeInPlace ()". I used "this" in the example just for simplicity and did not know it mattered, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue!

Turns out, checkPawnIsSatisfied has to receive this.curPawn as an argument so I added a line that passes it as an argument to the method and it started working!

```
  List <CodeInstruction> newCodes = new List<CodeInstruction> {
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldfld, curPawnFieldInfo),
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Call, randomizeInPlaceMethodInfo),
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Stfld, curPawnFieldInfo),
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldarg_0),
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Ldfld, curPawnFieldInfo),
    new CodeInstruction (OpCodes.Call, checkPawnIsSatisfiedMethodInfo),
  };
```